# Change style on attributes, remove bullet list

Tags: css, attributes

I finally find this code to show the attributes on a single product page, but I would like to change the style of the attributes list, i would like to replace the bullets with icons.
How can i do it?
thanks in advance

```
function isa_woocommerce_all_pa(){

    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    if ( ! $attributes ) {
        return;
    }

    $out = '<ul class="custom-attributes">';

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {


        // skip variations
        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
        continue;
        }
        $name = $attribute->get_name();
        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
            // get the taxonomy
            $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
            // get the tax object
            $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);
            // get tax label
            if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
                $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
            } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
                if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
                   $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
                }                
            }


            $out .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '">';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . esc_html( $tax_label ) . ': </span> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">';
            $tax_terms = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
                // Insert extra code here if you want to show terms as links.
                array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
            }
            $out .= implode(', ', $tax_terms);
            $out .= '</span></li>';

        } else {
            $value_string = implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() );
            $out .= '<li class="' . sanitize_title($name) . ' ' . sanitize_title( $value_string ) . '">';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . $name . ': </span> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">' . esc_html( $value_string ) . '</span></li>';
        }
    }

    $out .= '</ul>';

    echo $out;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'isa_woocommerce_all_pa', 25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the list items using the :before pseudo class and add your icons that way.

```
ul li:before {    
  content: '';
  background-image: url(‘icon.png’);
}
```

Comment: what about if i want to add "fa icon"?
I was actually triyng to add a different icon for the 2 different attributes.

Comment: I try to add this class to the code above: class="fa fa-camera-retro
but it adds the same icon to the 2 different attributes.


            $out .= '<li class="fa fa-camera-retro
class="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '">';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-label">' . esc_html( $tax_label ) . ': </span> ';
            $out .= '<span class="attribute-value">';
            $tax_terms = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

Comment: If you’re looking to use font awesome with a pseudo class they have some good examples in their documentation https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements. In your example why are you declaring class twice in the li?

Comment: ok i am bit confuse. I try to modify the previous code like that:

Comment: function isa_woocommerce_all_pa(){
  
    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
  
    if ( ! $attributes ) {
        return;
    }
  
    $out = '<ul class="custom-attributes">';

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
      if($attribute[‘label']==‘Cuisine Type’) {
      echo '<p class=“fa li”><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><label>' . html_entity_decode($attribute[‘label']) .     ':</label>';
      echo '<span> ' . $attribute['attribute'] . '</span></p>';
      }

Comment: if($attribute[‘label']==‘Diet’) {
      echo '<p class=“fa li”><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><label>' . html_entity_decode($attribute[‘label']) .     ':</label>';
      echo '<span> ' . $attribute['attribute'] . '</span></p>';
      }

    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
  
    echo $out;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'isa_woocommerce_all_pa', 25);

Comment: The code i just post is all together. What i tried to do is, show the attributes in the page (which works fine) 
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

After i try to get each attribute and give them a class and icon (but did not worked out).
  foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
      if($attribute[‘label']==‘Cuisine Type’) {

Can you tell where i am wrong?

Comment: Couple things to consider: First, do you have a link where this I can view this? Second, have you included the fontawesome stylesheet link? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">`. Finally, it's much easier to review if you format the code you post.

Comment: I am sorry for the code format, but i dont have a lot of characters left.
However, i did not add the link, i add the Font Awesome plugin to WP.
the link is: https://sootasty.net/store/dinner/sicilian-dinner/
You can see there are 2 Attributes after the short description on the right of the pictures. That's what i am looking to customize the class and add an icon for each attribute.
thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not seeing the `<ul class="custom-attributes">` on this page, but I did throw the fa icon in there and it worked (https://monosnap.com/file/gwsE6xCSXt1Kt3g3cQhhrH6DxLQHf6). I also noticed that you have multiple font-awesome links in the network tab. Is there a reason you are using two versions? Do you have a page where you're using the PHP above and the classes exist?

Comment: i don't know if im using the PHP above and the classes exist, i just know that i find the code above and i dont know how to add the icon and classes.

How can i find the multiple font-awesome links in the network tab?

I would like to use the first code that i posted, the 
`function isa_woocommerce_all_pa(){ `
because it actually shows the attributes without the tab.
Can you tell where to add the class and icon please?

thanks

Comment: If you want to use the same PHP above then try this adding this css: `li.**attributeclass**::before {  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f004";}`. The '\f004' is the unicode for the font awesome icon and will need to be updated for whatever icon you want. Make sure the li class matches whatever attribute class is being rendered via your PHP code.

Comment: ok i will try.
Is there any way to contact you in private for some payed jobs?
thanks a lot